# Who was the medieval author who addressed readers 1000 years in the future?

Tags: middle-ages, literature

I'm trying to remember the author of a quotation, where the author addresses the reader in the far future. It's says something like "if you are reading this in 100 or perhaps 1000 years I hope the reader forgives me my foibles". I think it's in the epilogue of the book.

I thought it was Henry of Huntingdon or Gerald of Wales but cannot find anything like that. Probably a British medieval author, but I'm starting to wonder if I've totally misremembered.

Anyone have any idea?
Thanks!

Comment: Are you absolutely sure it's a medieval book author and not, say, an Edwardian poet?

Comment: Are you sure it isn't Nostradamus, who lived during the Renaissance?

Comment: There's also the fictionalized Claudius who opens Robert Graves' *I, Claudius* that way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're thinking of [Henry of Huntingdon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry_of_Huntingdon), a 12th century historian. The [quote](http://books.google.com/books?id=e02Hp6kB7FIC&pg=PA119) begins, "Now I speak to you who will be living in the third millennium..."

Comment: A source (namely Historia Anglorum) would improve this answer.

Comment: The quote in question was initially part of an Epilogue to his Seventh Book of History, which was then followed by an Eighth Book, containing three of his Letters; then by a Ninth Book of Miracles, taken from [Bede](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bede); and by a Tenth Book, ending in a line introducing an Eleventh Book, itself followed by what appears to be just that. Modern scholarship, however, seems to have discarded the portions between the Seventh and Tenth Books as insertions, renumbering the latter as the Eighth, and regarding the Eleventh Book as the work of a later author.

Comment: [Four](http://la.wikisource.org/wiki/Historia_Anglorum) [relevant](http://books.google.com/books?id=O6U5BTD0-rYC&pg=PR10) [links](http://archive.org/details/chroniclehenryh01foregoog/page/n296) [supporting](http://archive.org/details/henriciarchidia00unkngoog/page/n331) my previous comment.

Comment: It was Henry of Huntingdon! Fantastic stuff, thank you!